# horizontal ProgressBar is not full parent width

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am adding progress bar to my application AppBarLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="?attr/appBarLayoutTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="?attr/toolbarPopupTheme"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progress_loader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/greyishWhite"
        android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
        android:maxWidth="2000dp"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Everything looks ok in portrait mode:

[image]

But on landscape mode it doesn't take full parent width:

[image]

How can I force ProgressBar take full with at all times.

**ANSWER:**

Thanks @Mahavir Jain for guiding to the right path:

at the end all needed to do was change

```
android:indeterminateOnly="true"
```

to

```
android:indeterminate="true"
```

Comment: have you tried removing `android:maxWidth="2000dp"` from your `ProgressBar?

Comment: Yes, thats, why I added it in the first place, I thiught maybe progress bar has some kind of max width set by default, so I tried overrising it, but it didn't helped

Comment: Are  you wrapping `AppBarLayout` in some other layout?

Comment: Yes, a CoordinatorLayout which is inside DrawerLayout

Comment: This is not issue of your progressbar view. Check parents of this view. Somewhere in tablet xml or dimens you are settings margins or padding

Comment: @antanas_sepikas share your whole layout\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove below line.

> android:indeterminateOnly="true"

android:indeterminateOnly
Restricts to ONLY indeterminate mode (state-keeping progress mode will not work).

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_loader"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="100"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:indeterminate="true"` or try this `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` instead of

```
style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```